# merging rows and putting certain columns to end of row instead of making a list

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am wondering if there is a way to append data rather than make a `list` of data when doing something like a `groupby()`.

What I am wanting to do is take a `dataframe` like this:

```
index NAME  ID  COLOR
0   Tim     1   red
1   Sally   2   red
2   Rob     3   green
3   Sally   2   blue
4   Sally   2   purple
```

And then merge the rows to make this:

```
index NAME  ID  COLOR1  COLOR2  COLOR3 
0   Tim     1   red
1   Sally   2   red     blue    purple
2   Rob     3   green
```

I know how to `agg()` with `groupby()` but am trying to figure out appending rather than making a `list` in a field, with this `dataframe` it would be a `list` in the `COLOR` field.

Comment: check Q&A No. 10

Comment: `df.set_index(['NAME', 'ID', df.groupby(['NAME', 'ID']).cumcount() + 1]).unstack()`

Comment: @BENY that helps but I need ALL columns to follow along